# Laravel Livewire Edit Role Spatie

Tags: laravel, edit

**Help, I work with laravel and spatie for roles and permissions.
I want to edit my permissions
with a checkbox list
from a window Attached code:**

**En el componente:**

```
    public $role;
    public $rol_id, $name;

    public $chek = [];

    public function mount(Role $role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;
        $this->data = $role->toArray();
        $this->chek = $this->role->permissions()->pluck('id')->toArray();
    }
    protected $rules =[
        'role.name' => 'required'      
    ];
    
    public function render()
    {               
        $permisos = Permission::all();
        return view('roles.edit-rol-component', compact('permisos'));
    }

    public function update(){
        $role = $this->role;
        $this->validate([
            'role.name' => 'required',
        ]);
        $this->role->save();
        $role->syncPermissions(['permission'=> $this->chek]);
        $this->emit('alert','success','El rol se editó correctamente.');
        $this->closeModalWithEvents([
            RolComponent::getName() => 'renderEvent']);
            
    }
```

**In the view, the list generator shows me but it marks the checks wrong**

```
@foreach($permisos as $key => $value)
    <label class="inline-flex items-center">
          <input wire:model.defer="chek.{{$value->id}}"  
          type="checkbox" value="{{ $value->id }}" 
         class="form-checkbox h-4 w-4 text-green-500"  
          @if($role->permissions->contains($value->id)) checked @endif >
          <span class="ml-3 text-sm">{{ $value->name }} </span>                                
    </label>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACNfO.png)

I am doing the edit / delete this way (as shown in the image)

Blade

```
<table class="table card-table table-vcenter text-nowrap table-hover table-striped datatable fs-5">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Permissions</th>
        <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($roles as $id => $single)

        @php
        $badgeColor = ['badge bg-blue-lt',
                        'badge bg-azure-lt',
                        'badge bg-purple-lt',
                        'badge bg-pink-lt',
                        'badge bg-indigo-lt',
                        'badge bg-red-lt',
                        'badge bg-orange-lt',
                        'badge bg-cyan-lt',
                        'badge bg-yellow-lt',
                        'badge bg-green-lt'
                    ];
        @endphp

        <tr>
        <td>{{ $id + 1 }}.</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{!! strtoupper($single->label) !!}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-list">
            @foreach ($single->permissions as $permission)
            <span class="{{ $badgeColor[rand(0, 9)] }} fs-5">{{ $permission->label }} <span class="ps-1" style="cursor: pointer" wire:click='revokePermission({{ $single->id }}, {{ $permission->id }})'>x</span></span>
            @endforeach
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-end">
            <button class="btn btn-danger p-1 fs-6"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Component:

```
public function revokePermission($roleId, $permissionId)
    {
        $role = Role::findOrFail($roleId);
        $permission = ModelsPermission::findOrFail($permissionId);
        $role->revokePermissionTo($permission->name);
        $this->render();
    }
```

Comment: What would it be like if I wanted to edit the role?